# Magento: Catalog and product view price incl tax (VAT) is incorrect

Tags: magento, rounding-error

I have looked online to find a solution to my problem but can’t see an answer to that specific issue.

I’m using Magento CE 1.8.0 
The prices in the catalogue are excluding VAT 
VAT is set at 20% 
The system is set as Prices exclude Tax 
The front end catalog list and product page are set to show both prices excluding VAT and including VAT.

My issue is that the price including VAT on some products is out by 1p on the catalog list and product view, although it is correct at checkout.

For example a product priced at £34.49 ex VAT shows a price inc VAT of £41.38 in the list view and product page (which is incorrect) and £41.39 in the checkout page (which is correct).

The issue is that I have a Google merchant feed that is sending the correct price inc VAT (£41.39) to Google and they’re complaining that the price on the website is different (even if it’s just 1p).

I have seen plenty of people with the ckeckout totals being incorrect while the catalog price is correct but not the other way around.
Has anyone got any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem and in researching it found out that certain settings in System > Configuration > SALES > Tax > Calculation Settings can cause rounding errors.

This may have the solution for you:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-ce-18-ee-113-tax-calc

Comment: Could you quote the relevant section of the link here?

Comment: The entire link is relevant and has tables I don't know how to reproduce here.  You need to have a look at your settings in System > Configuration > SALES > Tax > Calculation Settings and view your settings for "Catalog Prices" and "Tax Calculation Method Based On."  If you have Unit Price and Row total both selected as 'OK' for "Including & Excluding tax" you may get rounding errors.